# Finding a frequency of numbers in a list

Tags: python

```
from collections import Counter
f = open('input.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
counter = 0
freq = []
for line in lines:
    conv_int = int(line)
    counter = counter + conv_int
    freq.append(counter)
for i in freq:
    print(Counter(freq))
print(counter)
```

This code loops through a text file with various negative and positive numbers and adds them together starting from zero. However I was wondering how to find how many times each number occurs in this file?

Comment: Please explain what the "product of this file" means.

Answer (score 0):

Your file has an integer on each line, and you want the total sum and the frequency of each integer, right? Try this.

```
from collections import Counter
with open("input.txt", "rt") as f:
    total = 0
    count = Counter()
    for line in f:
        conv_int = int(line)
        total += conv_int
        count[conv_int] += 1
    print(count)
    print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Collection's `Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is expecting an iterable as an argument and not an item:

```
import collections

with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    numbers = [int(line) for line in input_file]
    numbers_sum = sum(numbers)
    numbers_frequency = collections.Counter(numbers)
```

But if efficiency is not an issue for you and you're just trying to `sum` all numbers in a file and `count` their frequency, you don't need to import a library just to do that:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    numbers = [int(line) for line in input_file]
    numbers_sum = sum(numbers)
    numbers_frequency = {n: numbers.count(n) for n in set(numbers)}
```

Comment: Your second method gives me another idea: `counter = Counter(int(line) for line in input_file)`, then `total = sum(x * k for x, k in counter.items())`.